# Is there a way to limit the amount of CPU a c++ application uses

Tags: c++, cpu-usage

I'm working on a program that calculates the recaman sequence. I want to calculate and then later visualize thousands or millions of terms in the sequence. However, I've noticed that it is taking up 10% of CPU, and the task manager says it has very high power usage. I don't want to damage the computer, and am willing to sacrifice speed for the safety of the computer. Is there a way to limit the CPU usage or battery consumption level of this application?

This is for Windows 10.

```
//My Function for calculating the sequence
//If it helps, you could look up 'Recaman Sequence' on google

void processSequence(int numberOfTerms) {
    int* terms;
    terms = new int[numberOfTerms];

    terms[0] = 0;
    cout << "Term Number " << 0 << " is: " << 0 << endl;

    int currentTermNumber = 1;
    int lastTerm = 0;
    int largestTerm = 0;

    for (currentTermNumber; currentTermNumber < numberOfTerms; currentTermNumber++) {
        int thisTerm;
        bool termTaken = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < numberOfTerms; j++) {
            if (terms[j] == lastTerm - currentTermNumber) {
                termTaken = true;
            }
        }

        if (!termTaken && lastTerm - currentTermNumber > 0) {
            thisTerm = lastTerm - currentTermNumber;
        }
        else {
            thisTerm = lastTerm + currentTermNumber;
        }

        if (thisTerm > largestTerm) {
            largestTerm = thisTerm;
        }
        lastTerm = thisTerm;

        cout << "Term Number " << currentTermNumber << " is: " << thisTerm << endl;
    };

    cout << "The Largest Term Number Was: " << largestTerm << endl;

    delete[] terms;
}
```

Comment: 10% of the CPU isn't really anything to worry about..

Comment: Also IIRC it's usually the OS that will handle stuff like this automatically and probably isn't worth worrying about. If anything I'd probably try and make the code itself more efficient.

Comment: Ok, but should I worry about the high battery consumption?

Comment: I don't think this is gonna have a noticeable effect on your battery personally.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to visualize this pattern on a number line next, and I hope the CPU usage doesn't get any higher.

Comment: Intentionally slowing down a program doesn't make sense.  Worst thing you'd do is not save on battery usage at all, it needs just as much, but make it more likely to run out since the program takes longer to finish and doesn't allow the machine to go idle.

Comment: Are you sure that it is really 10% and not 12%. I would guess you have a computer with 8 logical cores and your program only uses one of them. If you has 8 cores, there is no security reason for that limitation, but it is at 100% at one core.

Comment: Also on that note, I don't think your code itself is correct? I get different answers from your numbers as compared to here: https://oeis.org/A005132

Comment: I'm embarrased I reveiwed the code and found my bug. I forgot to add the term number calculated to the array of terms. This means that the pattern repeated the same number multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to use less CPU is to sleep from time to time for a short period, for example one or a few miliseconds.
You can do so by calling Sleep (Windows API), or current_thread::sleep (standard since C++11).

However,

- You won't ever physically damage your computer when using all cores at 100%. Most of videogames do so greedily anyway. The worst that can happen is an abrupt turn off and the unability to turn on again for the next few minutes, in case the CPU has reached a limit temperature (80-100°C). This security is indeed there to prevent anything dangerous and/or unrecoverable.
- It rarely makes sense to intentionally slow down your program like this. IF you are experiencing slowness in the user interface, you'd should move intensive processing to a non-UI thread.